# Can I have a Google Forms automatically capture a user's time zone?

Tags: google-forms, time-zone

I ask because I want to:

1. give users a grid to select days and times they are usually online. They might be anywhere in the world. Eg columns are Mon, Tues, ..., Sun, Rows are Midnight-3am, 3am-6am, ..., 9pm-Midnight etc.
2. graph the results, transposing their preferences to a single time zone (GMT/UTC probably) easily to see peaks.

Edit: I will look into scripts to do this for me, probably very simple once you know how. I can program Javascript, just completely new to Google Forms. Possible related links:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20342684/hidden-field-in-a-google-form

Answer (score 1):

Only Google Forms for G Suite accounts can automatically capture user data but it's only able to get the user email address.

The alternative is to include a question asking for the user time zone. Regarding the graph, Google Forms doesn't do the data adjustments so you should find a way to do that. This could be by using Google Sheets formulas, Google Apps Script or a third party tool.